# Sublime Text 3 custom PHP auto-completion does not work

Tags: php, sublimetext3

Here's the default auto-completion for "switch":

```
switch (variable) {
case 'value':
    # code...
    break;

default:
    # code...
    break;
}
```

but I wish to turn it into just:

```
switch ()
{
    case '':

    break;

    case '':

    break;
}
```

because I don't like to modify "#code here..." every time.

I navigated to

> "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\PHP"

and opened "switch(-).sublime-snippet" and modified it into:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[switch ($0)
{
case '$0':

    break;

case '$0':

    break;
}]]></content>
<tabTrigger>switch</tabTrigger>
<scope>source.php</scope>
<description>switch …</description>
```

But nothing works.
Is there any syntax error?
  Or do I modify the wrong file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tagged your question correctly, you modified the wrong file - you need to edit the Sublime Text 3 version. This is a bit more difficult to do directly, since the file is wrapped up in a `.sublime-package` zip archive. To get around this, install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net) (if you haven't already), then install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. Open the Command Palette, type ***`prv`*** to bring up the **`PackageResourceViewer`** options, select **`Open Resource`**, then navigate down to `PHP` and select the **`switch(-).sublime-snippet`** option. Edit it to your liking, save it, and you should be all set.

You probably also want to set your tab stops differently. Try this instead:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[switch ($1)
    {
    case '$2':
        $3
        break;

    case '$4':
        $5
        break;

    ${0:default:}
    }]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>switch</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.php</scope>
    <description>switch …</description>
</snippet>
```

Now, you can tab through the different areas, filling in the info as you go, ending up at the bottom with a `default` option, that you can just hit <kbd>Delete</kbd> on to erase if you don't want it. With your original version, after typeing `switch`<kbd>Tab</kbd>, you would have ended up with 3 different cursors, one at each of the `$0` locations. Check out the [snippets reference](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is completely solved.  And good reminder for variable rule.